# Libgdx stage buttons touch event at wrong position

Tags: java, button, libgdx, viewport

I got a problem with my libgdx stage buttons.

My game is running in 16/9 with a FitViewport. But I'm trying to make my HUD responsive to multiple screen aspect ratio's. For example I want my pause button instead of this (its still drawing in the fitviewport which is set to 16/9):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF6VR.png] (Image with working buttons in 16/9)

I fixed this by adding this line of code (which I also used for my background)

```
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

The buttons are drawing right now like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/icxS3.png] (Image with buttons which still got the old touch event from the first image)

Now I get to the real problem. The buttons are drawing like I want them to get drawn. But the touch event still happens at the old button places from my first picture. Does anyone know any better way to solve this? I tried looking into multiple viewport but couldn't really find a good way to do this with multiple viewports.

Comment: You cannot use glViewport like that in combination with a 16/9 FitViewport. Also: Do stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true) in resize.

Comment: @noone that Doesn't seem to work. Also I found glViewport in a libgdx example for a background behind a fitviewport shouldnt this be used this way?

Comment: You can use this, but then you have to "reapply" the stage's viewport afterwards via stage.getViewport().apply()

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `glViewport` if you are using a Stage, because the Stage is using a Viewport class that is trying to manage `glViewport` calls. This will really mess you up.

Next, make sure you are calling `stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true)` in `resize` as @noone said. Stage2d is never going to behave correctly if you don't do this.

Finally, use ExtendViewport instead of FitViewport. If you need FitViewport for the game itself, then use a separate Stage instance with its own Viewport for the UI. You can combine the input for your two stages using an InputMultiplexor.

Comment: Im gonna try using a InputMultiplexor I just wanted a good way to combine hud and the game itself with a 16/9 aspect ratio and also a responsive hud. Thanks for explaining glviewport a bit :-)